# Getting raw h264 packets from USB camera on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, h.264

I am trying to receive H264 frames from a USB webcamera connected to my Raspberry PI

Using the RPi Camera Module I can run the following command to get H264 data outputted in stdin: `raspivid -t 0 -w 640 -h 320 -fps 15 -o -` with **close to  zero latency**

Is there an equivalent function to do this with a USB camera? I have two USB cameras I would like to do this with.

Using `ffprobe /dev/videoX` I get the following output: (shorted down to the important details):

```
$ ffprobe /dev/video0
...
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
Duration: N/A, start: 18876.273861, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1280x720, 147456 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc

$ ffprobe /dev/video1
...
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video1':
Duration: N/A, start: 18980.783228, bitrate: 115200 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 800x600, 115200 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc


$ ffprobe /dev/video2
...
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video2':
Duration: N/A, start: 18998.984143, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, -5 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 2000k tbc
```

As far as I can tell two of them are not H264, which will need to be "decoded" to H264 so I understand there is added a bit latency there. But the third one (video2) is H264 so I should be able to get data from it? I've tried to just pipe it out with CAT but it says I got invalid arguments.

I've come as far as using FFMPEG might be the only option here. Would like to use software easily available for all RPi (apt install).

**Bonus question regarding H264 packets:** When I stream the data from raspivid command to my decoder it works perfectly. But if I decide to drop the 10 first packets then it never initializes the decoding process and just shows a black background. Anyone know what might be missing in the first packets that I might be able to recreate in my software so I dont have to restart the stream for every newly connected user?

**EDIT: Bonus Question Answer:** After googling around I see that the first two frames `raspivid` sends me are. So by ignoring the two first frames my decoder wont "decode" properly. So if I save those frames and send them first to all new users it works perfectly. Seems like these are used in some kind of initial process.

```
0x27 = 01 00111 = type 7    Sequence parameter set (B-frame)
0x28 = 01 01000 = type 8    Picture parameter set (B-frame)
```

Comment: You have that backwards. “Raw” =“raw”. H264 is encoded. Decoding h264 produces raw frames.

Comment: @szatmary Thanks a lot, edited main post to reflect that. (removed "raw" in front of H264)

Comment: Updated main questions since I found answer for my Bonus Question. Also my research have dragged me to this command which seems to output H264 data from the camera. ```ffmpeg -i /dev/video2 -c copy -f rawvideo pipe: 1``` the problem seems like my decoder dont get any 0x27 0x28 frames which seems to be nessesary since RPi camera was not working without? Also I cannot change the framerate or resolution it seems like with that command? (Like hardware change as raspivid does?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us get the **data flow** right.  For the Raspi cam:

1. The [Raspi camera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/README.md) is connected by [CSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Serial_Interface) (Camera Serial Interface) to the Raspi.  This link carries uncompressed, raw image data.
2. [raspivid](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspivid.md) talks to the embedded GPU of the Raspi to access the image data and also asks the GPU to perform H.264 encoding, which always adds some latency (you could use [raspiyuv](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspiyuv.md) to get the raw uncompressed data, possibly with less latency).

USB webcams typically transfer uncompressed, raw image data.  But some also transfer H.264 or jpeg encoded data.

Next, the **[Video for Linux API version 2](https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-new/uapi/v4l/v4l2.html)** was not made for shell pipes, so you can't get data out of a */dev/videoX* with cat.  You need some code to perform IOCTL calls to negotiate what and how to read data from the device.  ffmpeg does exactly that.

Regarding your bonus question, you might try the [--inline option](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md) of raspivid, which forces the stream to include PPS and SPS headers on every I-frame.

Next, outputting H.264 data from ffmpeg, using *-f rawvideo* looks wrong to me, since *rawvideo* means uncompressed video.  You could instead try *-f h264* to force raw H.264 videooutput format:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video2 -c copy -f h264 pipe:1
```

Finally, you actually want to get a **H.264 stream from your USB webcam**.  Since the image data comes uncompressed from the camera, it first has to be encoded to H.264.  The sensible option on the Raspi is to use the hardware encoder, since using a software encoder like x264 would consume too much CPU resources.

If you have an ffmpeg that was configured using *--enable-mmal* and/or *--enable-omx-rpi*, you can use ffmpeg to talk to the hardware H.264 encoder.

Otherwise, take a look at [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) and its [omxh264enc](https://gist.github.com/mitsuhito/ad3ae3e341726687457c) element, eg. [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/what-speed-can-i-expect-from-the-hardware-h264-encoding).  gstreamer can also [talk to v4l2 devices](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-v4l2src.html).

Comment: Thanks! So I've actually yesterday got this to work by using this command:

```ffmpeg -i /dev/video1 -r 30000/1001 -vcodec libx264 -pass 1 -coder 0 -bf 0 -flags -loop -wpredp 0 -f h264 pipe:1```

"libx264" encodes with 0.194x speed and decodes fine. "copy" has 1x but wont decode. (Broadway Javascript decoder).

What is different between libx264 and "copy"? Camera is h264 also.

Output of ffprobe: ```Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video1':``` and ```Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, -5 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 2000k tbc```

Comment: libx264 is the ffmpeg name for using the [x264 encoder](https://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html), that is software, very slow on a Raspberry.  So yes, no decoding error, but too slow.

Comment: Edit: did save two version, the libx264 is "baseline" and the copy is "main" seems like Broadway only supports baseline, so I have somehow to get the h264 stream converted near realtime to "baseline". Is that possible?

Comment: "Changing" the [H.264 profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles) from main to baseline requires decoding +  reencoding.  This is nothing one would want to do on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Oh well, then this camera is useless :) might have to look into the gstreamer and have one receiver to see if they can make it html friendly. But the camera have two inputs, one h264 main, and one raw video. Might be possible to use raw video instead to encode only using rpis hw encoder (?)